# Formula field in related list displayed in Classic but not in Lightning

Tags: lightning, formula-field, related-list

As we were validating data that we just loaded, we encountered a strange issue on a specific user:

A formula field contained in a related list is not calculated in Lightning whereas the user can clearly see it in Classic.

Following the standard troubleshooting procedure we checked:

- **The page layout** : there is one unique page layout for all users
- **The field level security** : the user's profile allows to read the field
- **The data itself** : the formula field displays as expected in classic, workbench confirms that the data is here

My questions:

- What could we have forgotten in troubleshoot process which could explain the gap between Lightning and Classic ?
- What can make the field formula field displayed well in Classic but not in Lightning ?
- How come this kind of issue be user specific and where could we configure this to prevent these issues in the future ?

Thanks in advance,

NB: We used the standard related lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to fix the issue even if, however, the cause of the problem isn't clear.

The field which was not displayed is the ProductCode at the Opportunity Product level.

The field wasn't displaying because the preferred currency of the user was different to the one of the pricebook entry of the opportunity product.

We are still sceptic about the explanation of the problem as:

- The issue is not happening in classic
- Functionaly speaking, a user shouldn't be limited by his preferred currency (Example : a british company that sells in both EUR or GBP depending on their customer)
- There is no "hard link" between the preferred currency and the pricebook entry's currency (whereas there is one between the opportunity's one and the pricebook entry's one)

If anyone could give deeper explanations about the root source if this issue it would be great.

Comment: very odd; if you post some screen shots and the example formula; those of use with access to Premier Support my be able to log a case for this (you should also check Known Issues)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but thought I would add a recent similar finding with fairly different causality.

Scenario: Using Lightning ONLY. Custom currency field on a child custom object. Custom parent object has a related list which should display this custom currency field.

Issue: Parent object doesn't seem to have visibility of the child's custom currency object.

Solution: Changed the related list type from Default to Enhanced on the Lightning Page. Now the currency field shows up.

Reason: Unknown